# python - django autentication - anonymous user after login

Tags: python, django, django-authentication

I have a django server which acts as an API (i.e. listens to requests and returns data ONLY), and I want this API to be accessible only to authenticated users.
I read about the django authentication system, and tried to implement it according to the documentation (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/).

I wrote a small web-page just to test the authentication - login was successful (server was able to authenticate and login the user), but when attempting to reach a restricted view I have no access, and the request.user received is an AnonymousUser instead of the logged in user.

I am using Python 3.6.5 and Django 2.0.4

Server code:

```
@csrf_exempt
def dologin(request):
    username = request.POST.get('username')
    password = request.POST.get('password')
    if not username or not password:
        return HttpResponse('missing username or password', status=400)
    user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        login(request, user)
        return HttpResponse(user)
    else:
        return HttpResponse('bad credentials', status=422)

def dologout(request):
    logout(request)
    return HttpResponse('success')

@login_required()
def testAccess(request):
    return HttpResponse('ok')

def checkUser(request):
    u = "anonymous" if not request.user.is_authenticated else request.user.username
    return HttpResponse(u)
```

Client code:

```
<label>username:</label>
<input type="text" id="uin"/>
<label>username:</label>
<input type="text" id="pin"/>
<button id="inbtn">login</button>
<button id="outbtn">logout</button>
<button id="test">test access</button>
<button id="check">check user</button>

<div id="res"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    $("#inbtn").click(function(){
        u = $("#uin").val();
        p = $("#pin").val();
        d = {username: u, password: p};
        $.post("http://10.0.0.9:8000/login/", d, function(data){
            $("#res").html(data);
        }).fail(function(xhr, status, error){
            $("#res").html(xhr.responseText + " - " + xhr.status);
        });
    });

    $("#outbtn").click(function(){
        $.get("http://10.0.0.9:8000/logout/", function(data){
            $("#res").html(data);
        }).fail(function(xhr, status, error){
            $("#res").html(xhr.responseText + " - " + xhr.status);
        });
    });

    $("#test").click(function(){
        $.get("http://10.0.0.9:8000/testaccess/", function(data){
            $("#res").html(data);
        }).fail(function(xhr, status, error){
            $("#res").html(xhr.responseText + " - " + xhr.status);
        });
    });

    $("#check").click(function(){
        $.get("http://10.0.0.9:8000/checkuser/", function(data){
            $("#res").html(data);
        }).fail(function(xhr, status, error){
            $("#res").html(xhr.responseText + " - " + xhr.status);
        });
    });
</script>
```

(I'm running everything locally, that's why I use 10.0.0.9 which is my pc's ip)

As i wrote before - after a successful login, clicking 'test access' results in a 404 response, and clicking 'check user' returns 'anonymous' (and by debugging the server I know the user is indeed AnonymousUser)

Comment: Have you enabled [sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/sessions/)? I don't recall where it specified this, but I think you might run into this issue if you don't have sessions enabled...because Django only knows you've logged in from the session cookie.

Comment: yes, sessions is enabled (by default btw)

Answer (score 2):

I suspect your problem is with the session data.

After authentication and login, the user is set within a single [django session](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/sessions/). A HTTP cookie (per default named `sessionid`) will be set with an session number.

For every subsecuent request you need to also pass `sessionid` to the server, so that the server can identify which user this new request belongs to.

You should read up on how to get the `sessionid` cookie after login and how to send that same `sessionid` along with the new requests.

Comment: Do I need to retrieve and send the sessionId manually in the client-side?
I was under the impression that it happens automatically.

Edit: Btw, looks like you are right. After the login, a session key is assigned, but further requests arrive with no session key

Comment: The session id should get sent automatically when there are redirects or reloads, but I'm not sure what happens if there is no page reload or redirect.